# echo the process_id of Terminal started from shell script

Tags: shell, process, terminal, echo

Working with osx in my shell script I'm starting terminal like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
tell application "Terminal" 
do script my_script...
end tell
```

How can I echo the process_id of this Terminal to kill it in future?
Or can I get tty of this terminal maybe?

Comment: what is in my_script ? notice tell is an osascript command.

Comment: my_script is a number of terminal commands. it doesn't matter what in it. I can add anything to this script.

Answer (score 0):

I apologise; a style of speech that seems not to convert well into English . . . and I was being a bit lazy.  Fault acknowledged; I will be more explicit.

```
#!/bin/sh
tell application "Terminal"
   do script "echo $$ > terminals.pid; my_script . . . "
end tell
```

At some appropriate point afterwards

```
kill -kill  `cat terminals.pid` 
(or kill -s kill)
```

as needed.

Comment: thanks. that's what I needed. but the answer came too late& after 4 month :(